# Assign an object in a select in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I modified the original plunker of

[original documentacion ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

I am trying to assign in the "bogus" button the black object.

It is the same object but is not selected in the drop down with ng-model binding

{name:'black', shade:'dark'}

you can see in

[plunker forked](http://embed.plnkr.co/zVECOfuVMsqf6GOVokB9/preview)

Why the double binding is not working???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because it's not the same object, try using a filter to get your black item as in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sCxOqn0CvCW4zXWjTNNU?p=preview)

```
$filter('filter')($scope.colors, {name : 'black'});
```

If you use a console.log of the $filter black item you'll see there is a $$hashKey: "object:3" value added to the item, that's why it doesn't take it as the same object.

Comment: Thank you
I did something similar with angular.foreach, but I did not understand why the new object ... is not assigned.

The filter does something like foreach... but mor clean/elegant